# Postgres: query average landed cost from prior records

Tags: postgresql, recursive-cte

I have a query from my postgres tables that looks like this:

| date | sku | incoming_unit_qty | incoming_unit_cost | landed_unit_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $3.00 | 0 |
| 2023-08-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $2.00 | 0 |
| 2023-08-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $1.00 | 0 |
| 2023-09-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $3.50 | 500 |
| 2023-09-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $2.50 | 1,000 |
| 2023-09-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $1.50 | 1,500 |
| 2023-10-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $4.00 | 750 |
| 2023-10-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $3.00 | 1,500 |
| 2023-10-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $2.00 | 2,250 |
| 2023-11-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $3.50 | 250 |
| 2023-11-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $2.50 | 500 |
| 2023-11-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $1.50 | 750 |

I am trying to generate a `view` that would calculate for each sku and each date, the weighted average cost. The result should look as follows:

| date | sku | incoming_unit_qty | incoming_unit_cost | landed_unit_qty | landed_unit_cost | average_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $3.00 | 0 | $0.00 | $3.00 |
| 2023-08-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $2.00 | 0 | $0.00 | $2.00 |
| 2023-08-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $1.00 | 0 | $0.00 | $1.00 |
| 2023-09-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $3.50 | 500 | $3.00 | $3.33 |
| 2023-09-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $2.50 | 1,000 | $2.00 | $2.33 |
| 2023-09-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $1.50 | 1,500 | $1.00 | $1.33 |
| 2023-10-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $4.00 | 750 | $3.33 | $3.71 |
| 2023-10-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $3.00 | 1,500 | $2.33 | $2.71 |
| 2023-10-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $2.00 | 2,250 | $1.33 | $1.71 |
| 2023-11-01 | sku-1 | 1,000 | $3.50 | 250 | $3.71 | $3.54 |
| 2023-11-01 | sku-2 | 2,000 | $2.50 | 500 | $2.71 | $2.54 |
| 2023-11-01 | sku-3 | 3,000 | $1.50 | 750 | $1.71 | $1.54 |

How can I achieve this?

I have tried the below recursive CTE query, which results in the following error message `recursive reference to query "lc" must not appear within a subquery LINE 15: (select average_cost from lc where date < lc.date and sku = lc.sku order by date desc limit 1) as landed_unit_cost`. While I understand the error message, I cannot find a solution that doesn't involve a recursive subquery.

```sql
with recursive lc as (
    (select distinct on (sku)
      *,
      0 as landed_unit_cost,
      incoming_unit_cost as average_cost
    from lc_history
    order by sku, date)
  union
    select
      l.*,
      (l.incoming_unit_qty*l.incoming_unit_cost + l.landed_unit_qty*l.landed_unit_cost) / (l.incoming_unit_qty + l.landed_unit_qty) as average_cost
    from (
      select
        *,
        (select average_cost from lc where date < lc.date and sku = lc.sku order by date desc limit 1) as landed_unit_cost
      from lc_history
    ) l
)
select * from lc order by date, sku;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What formula are you using for the calc?  Every time I've done average or moving landed cost, it was `sum(qty * cost) / sum(qty)` for all lines up to the current line.

Comment: The maths looks as follows (in pseudo-code): `landed_unit_cost = latest average_cost for same sku prior to current date` and `average_cost = (incoming_unit_qty*incoming_unit_cost + landed_unit_qty*landed_unit_cost) / (incoming_unit_qty + landed_unit_qty)`.

The issue that I encounter is that `average_cost` depends on `landed_unit_cost`, and `landed_unit_cost` relies on the prior value of `average_cost`, so I am struggling to translate this into SQL.

Comment: Here is a solution in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17D6V59IVjr7A4qm3-P1yfmckjmN8jhvuN2nKJi_AaxA/edit?usp=sharing) with the `query` function.
In order to make the `Iterative` sheet work, I've had to enable Iterative Calculations - otherwise there is a circular reference. That's why my intuition leads me towards recursive queries, but so far I haven't been able to translate this into postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a for loop in PL/pgSQL. It's not as elegant as an SQL query, but it works.

```sql
create type landed_cost as (
  date date,
  sku text,
  incoming_unit_qty integer,
  incoming_unit_cost real,
  landed_unit_qty integer,
  landed_unit_cost real,
  average_cost real
);

create function get_landed_costs()
  returns table (rec landed_cost)
 language plpgsql
 security definer
as $function$
declare
  row landed_cost;
  landed_unit_cost real;
begin
  create temporary table landed_costs of landed_cost;
  
  for row in select * from lc_history order by date
  loop
    landed_unit_cost := (select average_cost from landed_costs where date < row.date and sku = row.sku order by date desc limit 1);

    insert into landed_costs values (
      row.date, row.sku,
      row.incoming_unit_qty,
      row.incoming_unit_cost,
      row.landed_unit_qty,
      landed_unit_cost,
      (row.incoming_unit_qty*row.incoming_unit_cost + row.landed_unit_qty*coalesce(landed_unit_cost,0)) / (row.incoming_unit_qty + row.landed_unit_qty)
    );
  end loop;

  return query select * from landed_costs;
end;
$function$
;

select * from get_landed_costs();
```